# Remove strings which partially duplicate

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed, filter

I have a file of strings which are address and some value as below. It has duplicates by addresses, I need to remove all duplicates and leave all strings with unique addresses.

In-text:

`A0:E6:F8:48:F0:3F BB
A0:E6:F8:48:87:D7 B6
A0:E6:F8:48:F1:AF B9
A0:E6:F8:48:36:EB B5
A0:E6:F8:48:32:94 B5
A0:E6:F8:48:38:6F AF
A0:E6:F8:48:6C:FC B7
A0:E6:F8:48:31:6E B6
A0:E6:F8:48:87:DA B0
A0:E6:F8:48:F0:3F B1
A0:E6:F8:48:F1:AF B1
A0:E6:F8:48:6C:FC BA
A0:E6:F8:48:31:6E B5`

out-text:

`A0:E6:F8:48:F0:3F BB
A0:E6:F8:48:87:D7 B6
A0:E6:F8:48:F1:AF B9
A0:E6:F8:48:36:EB B5
A0:E6:F8:48:32:94 B5
A0:E6:F8:48:38:6F AF
A0:E6:F8:48:6C:FC B7
A0:E6:F8:48:31:6E B6
A0:E6:F8:48:87:DA B0`

This should work on all address of kind XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Comment: `sort` would also have worked fine : `sort -k1,1 -u` defines a sorting key on the first field (space-separated) then asks for unique output on this key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get unique records on basis of first field then try following.

```
awk '!a[$1]++'   Input_file
```

I am creating here an array named a where I am checking condition if any line's first field is NOT present into array a then print the line and increment it by 1(that specific 1st field) so that next time that entry will be eliminated from the printing it.

Comment: Great, it worked.